# Controlling CDF window size

Tags: cdf-format

I want to ask how can I control the `CDF` `WindowSize` in such a way that the end user can minimise its size upto some extent only. For example, If the `WindowSize` is less than or equal to {300,200}, then it should not be minimised but, it can be maximised.

```
Dynamic[(width = CurrentValue["WindowSize"][[1]];
        height = CurrentValue["WindowSize"][[2]];
 If[width <= 300, (width = 301), (width = CurrentValue["WindowSize"][[1]])];
 If[height <= 200, (height = 201), (height = CurrentValue["WindowSize"][[2]])];
 Panel[Button["Click1"], {width, height}, ImageSize -> {width, height}])]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code seems to be a possible start point, though far from satisfying:

```
CreateDocument[{
  Cell[BoxData[
    DynamicWrapperBox[

     RowBox[{"WindowSize: ",
       DynamicBox[ToBoxes[CurrentValue[WindowSize], StandardForm]]}],

     SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
      WindowSize -> {Max[300, CurrentValue[WindowSize][[1]]],
        Max[200, CurrentValue[WindowSize][[2]]]}]
     ]
    ]]}, WindowSize -> {300, 200}]
```